# Modulo % only prints one zero digit in C

Tags: c, printing, numbers, modulo, zero

I've been trying to work with modulos in my code for my school project, but I've encountered one "issue" :

In my program, I want to recover my results and transform them into (printed on stdout) percentages.

For example : I find my number (4 / 48), and I get "0.08333333333", multiply it by 100 to get "8.333333333", I will print the first number as an int (so it will basically output 8), and then I want to print the first two digits after that, so I will just use a modulo 10 to get "33".

But, my "issue" is when I try to print two zero digits, it will simply display one of them, as the result is zero, so there is no need to have multiple zeros.

I figured how to print both zero-digits like so :

```
    if (((int)(freq * 100) % 100) == 0) {
        my_put_nbr((int)(freq * 100) % 10);
        my_put_nbr((int)(freq * 100) % 10);
    } else
        my_put_nbr((int)(freq * 100) % 100);
```

where for example "freq" in this case is "8.333334" and will result in printing 8 then 33.

but I wanted to know if there was another actual proper way to do what I just did there.

I'm not very good at explaining things but I hope this is clear, otherwise please let me know.

Comment: "use a modulo 10 to get "33"" Modulo 10 will result in 0...9. Modulo 100 results in 0...99.

Comment: You can't use the `%` modulus operator on floating point value, you need `fmod()`, but an answer shows the accepted way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a value like `0.08333333` and you want to display it as `8.33`, just do

```
 printf( "%.2f\n", freq * 100.0 );
```

---

If you’re not allowed to use `printf`, then <strike>slap your instructor for making this harder than it needs to be</strike> it depends on how your `my_put_nbr` function is supposed to work and how you want to format the output.  If the function prints out integer *values* and your `freq` value is always between `0` and `1` and you just want to display `0.0833` as `833`, then all you need to do is

```
my_put_nbr( (int) freq * 10000 );
```

That will capture up to the first two digits following the decimal point, including zeros - that is, `0.0100` will be converted to `100`.

If your `my_put_nbr` is only supposed to print individual digits, then this takes a bit more work.  You could use a loop like so:

```
for ( long mag = 1; mag < 100000; mag *= 10 )
{
  if (freq * mag < 1) // prevents leading 0s from
    continue;         // being displayed

  int digit = (long) (freq * mag) % 10;
  my_put_nbr( digit );
}
```

I’m using `long` for my temporary calculations as `int` is not guaranteed to be wide enough to store 32-bit values (it’s very likely to be wide enough on any system built after 1990, but it is not guaranteed).

If that still doesn’t quite meet your needs, then it should at least give you some ideas.

Comment: I think I forgot to mention I coudn't use the printf function and this is why I was looking for that possibility, other than the printf.

Answer (score 1):

> when I try to print two zero digits, it will simply display one of them

You can try the following, it should print 2 digits.

```
printf("%2.2f", Value);
```

Comment: The first `2` in `%2.2` will be ignored though, since the total field width must be greater.